# "Tradeoff" usage

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

How is this word to be used in practice when a subject is also mentioned? 
I am interested in both the static situation of *dealing with/being into/being subject to* a tradeoff and the dynamic process of *accepting/entering/undergoing* one. What are the proper terms/expressions to be used in place of my gross tentatives in italic? Please mention more choices if available...

Comment: Can you provide more context or examples?

Comment: I simply need to describe the interaction of a subject and a tradeoff, that is to say more compactly and properly "Being in a position which imposes a tradeoff", and getting there. Or said otherwise, instead of just saying "The context X involves/implies/forces tradeoff Y" I need to say that someone in that context encounters *inevitably* tradeoff Y. So in the static case there must be a clear inevitability implied, in the dynamic case it shall remain there while leaving optionality in getting into that situation only.

Comment: Include a sample sentence to give an insight into the usage in context.

Answer (score 0):

For the static situation, perhaps you're interested instead in *considering the tradeoff*  [between `X` and `Y`] or *discussing the tradeoff*.  (*Accepting* the tradeoff is correct, if you're talking about someone accepting the fact that there exists a tradeoff.)

When engaging the dynamic situation of a tradeoff, you may be *negotiating the tradeoff*, analogously to negotiating  a mountain trail, or other delicate task. If you merely mean to make a choice within the situation of a tradeoff, you might say that you are *trading `X` for `Y`* or *trading away [some] `X` for [more/better/improved] `Y`*. All of these return to the root market metaphor which seems to be the origin of the phrase.